# How to split dataframe into multiple dataframes by their column datatypes using SparkSQL?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Below is the sample dataframe, I want to split this into multiple dataframes or rdd's based on their datatype

```
ID:Int
Name:String
Joining_Date: Date
```

I have 100+ columns in my data frame, Is there any inbuilt method to achieve this logic?

Comment: From your question it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you expand on it or better yet provide an example?

Comment: Could you please add sample data with datatypes and what output you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is not a build-in functionality to achieve that, nevertheless here is a way to separate one dataframe into multiple dataframes based on the column type.

First lets create some data:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, LongType, DateType

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  (0, 11, "t1", "s1", "2019-10-01"), 
  (0, 22, "t2", "s2", "2019-02-11"), 
  (1, 23, "t3", "s3", "2018-01-10"), 
  (1, 24, "t4", "s4", "2019-10-01")], ["i1", "i2", "s1", "s2", "date"])

df = df.withColumn("date", col("date").cast("date"))

# df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- i1: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- i2: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- s1: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- s2: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- date: date (nullable = true)
```

Then we will group the columns of the previous dataframe into a dictionary where the key with be the column type and the value a list with the columns that correspond to that type:

```py
d = {}
# group cols into a dict by type
for c in df.schema:
  key = c.dataType
  if not key in d.keys(): 
    d[key] = [c.name]
  else:
    d[key].append(c.name)

d
# {DateType: ['date'], StringType: ['s1', 's2'], LongType: ['i1', 'i2']}
```

Then we iterate though the keys(col types) and we generate the schema along with the corresponding empty dataframe for each item of the dictionary:

```py
type_dfs = {}
# create schema for each type
for k in d.keys():
  schema = StructType(
    [
      StructField(cname , k) for cname in d[k] 
    ])

  # finally create an empty df with that schema  
  type_dfs[str(k)] = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)

type_dfs
# {'DateType': DataFrame[date: date],
#  'StringType': DataFrame[s1: string, s2: string],
#  'LongType': DataFrame[i1: bigint, i2: bigint]}
```

Finally we can use the generated dataframes by accessing each item of the type_dfs:

```py
type_dfs['StringType'].printSchema()

# root
#  |-- s1: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- s2: string (nullable = true)
```